# A* algorithm reopen vertices

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic, graph

Consider the following pseudocode for the `A* search algorithm`:

```
A*(G, s, h)
  for each vertex u in V
    d[u] := f[u] := infinity
    color[u] := WHITE
    p[u] := u
  end for
  color[s] := GRAY
  d[s] := 0
  f[s] := h(s)
  INSERT(Q, s)
  while (Q != Ø)
    u := EXTRACT-MIN(Q)
    for each vertex v in Adj[u]
      if (w(u,v) + d[u] < d[v])
        d[v] := w(u,v) + d[u]
    f[v] := d[v] + h(v)
    p[v] := u
    if (color[v] = WHITE)
      color[v] := GRAY
      INSERT(Q, v)
    else if (color[v] = BLACK)
      color[v] := GRAY
      INSERT(Q, v)
    end if
      else
        ...
    end for
    color[u] := BLACK
  end while
```

Now - do I understand correctly that if **we want to find a path from the source vertex (`s`) to some destination vertex (let's name it `d`)** then we can simply *add a check* right after the `u := EXTRACT-MIN(Q)` statement like this:

```
    u := EXTRACT-MIN(Q)
    if (u = d) RETURN PATH
```

This is obviously correct in case we don't need to reopen vertices (`else if (color[v] = BLACK`), but ***is it correct*** in case **we have to reopen them** (for example, if the heuristic function is not monotonic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. If you find the destination node, then you'll never have to reopen anything; you can just return the path. By the properties of the A* algorithm (including an admissible heuristic), the first time you pop the destination node off the priority queue, you'll have a shortest path to it.

Comment: Actually, it's the first time you select the destination node for expansion, not the first time you encounter it. If you short-circuit the algorithm when you first generate the destination node, it's not guaranteed that you've found the shortest path to it.